# Removing the DirectoryReader object in Phonegap

Tags: cordova

How to remove a directory reade object created using the file API of phonegap?

Comment: Do you want to remove a directory or just the variable?

Comment: I dont want to remove the directory. I want to remove the directory reader object from the variable so that each time i can start a new directory read activity. currently i am unable to control the directory reader once i called .

Comment: I'm afraid I just don't understand what you are asking. If you assign a new value to a variable, you are, in essence, removing the last one.

Comment: Thank you Raymond for replying,  I have put the main part of my code in the following link, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12796807/how-to-control-the-directory-reader-activity-in-phonegap-file-api.